# How to use woocommerce API

Tags: ios, objective-c, wordpress, woocommerce

I was trying to use the woo API for my practice iOS app.
I guess it is ok to woocommerce as a backend tool for my ios app.

I went through the doc, listed here: http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#authentication-over-http

But can't get enough idea about what to do and how to do.

still i tried something as below:

```
NSURL * appUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1/localStore/wp-json/wc/v1/products"];
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:appUrl];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask * task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable location, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        NSLog(@"%@", response);


    }];

    [task resume];
```

and here is a response:

```
{ status code: 401, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 3415;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 04 Oct 2016 17:27:38 GMT";
    Expires = "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.17 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1q PHP/5.5.30 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.30";
} }
```

Can someone please guide me in the right direction. Also Do i need to create an api for all my customers so that i can create orders for them in the db. thank you!

Comment: Never-mind, I solved it. I need to add oAuth check with the request.